# Headers and footers over contents... How can i fix this?

Tags: html, css, pdf, dompdf

I have a big problem with position of contents. I have a large amount of content that is hidden under headers and footers. I want to have a margin-bottom/top for headers/footers on every page.

Here is my HTML document:

```css
@page {
            margin: 180px 50px;
        }

        #header {
            position: fixed;
            left: 0px;
            top: -180px;
            right: 0px;
            height: 300px;
            background-color: orange;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #footer {
            position: fixed;
            left: 0px;
            bottom: -180px;
            right: 0px;
            height: 300px;
            background-color: lightblue;
        }

        #footer .page:after {
            content: counter(page, upper-roman);
        }

        section {
            margin-top: 100px;
        }
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <h1>Widgets Express</h1>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <p class="page">Page </p>
</div>
<section>
    What is Lorem Ipsum?
    <br>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<br>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.<br>It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.<br>It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

    <br>Why do we use it?
    <br>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by <br>the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.
    <br>The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal <br>distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.
    <br>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem <br>Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
    <br>Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident,<br> sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).


    <br>Where does it come from?
    <br>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.
    <br>It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, <br>making it over 2000 years old.<br>Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source.<br>Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC.<br>This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance.<br>The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

    <br>The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced <br>below for those interested.<br>Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H.<br>Rackham.

    <br>Where can I get some?
    <br>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, <br>but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected hum<br>our, or randomised wo<br>rds which don't look <br>even slightly believable.<br>If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text.<br>All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet.<br>It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable.<br>The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.


    <br>5
    <br>paragraphs
    <br>words
    <br>bytes
    <br>lists
    <br>Start with 'Lorem
    <br>ipsum dolor sit amet...'
    <br>Generate Lorem Ipsum

</section>
```

The resulting PDF looks like this: http://3.1m.yt/28MKkWG.png

Comment: A screenshot is code is not code.

Comment: there is no jsfiddle link where we can see your code and run it..how would i fix it?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @PeeHaa. Added code for you.. https://jsfiddle.net/0w75t98f/

Comment: @ZakiMustafa Added code in my comments.

Comment: I updated the question to include the linked HTML source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use css @page to add margins to every page.
You're header then needs a negative margin.
As an example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    @page { margin-top: 50px; }
    .header { margin-top: -50px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">Header</div>
Rest of the page.
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: Added an example

Comment: This code make a header only on the first page.. I want all pages to have a header and all to have a margin bottom to don't be over my section code.

Comment: I have a fixed header and footer in my script with no changing header/footer values. So I use the css code `body { background: url('.$baseUrl.'/image//logo-print.png) left top no-repeat; padding-top: 100px; }`. This repeats the header/footer on every page because its a background image with header and footer inside it.

Comment: section {
            position: relative;
            top: 200px;
            bottom: 400px;
    }
Added this code for section and it makes a margin top for it but, now only footer is covering my text section..

Comment: You would use the same idea for the footer, push it into the page's bottom. FYI, you can use negative positioning instead of negative margins (e.g. `.header { top: -50px; }`).

Comment: @Paul. to clarify: you can't just add a margin to the `section` element. Dompdf does not re-apply margins to in-flow content when it's split across pages. You have to apply the margins to the page and push the header/footer into that margin using negative positioning or margins.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: orange;
    text-align: center;
}
#footer{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
#footer .page:after{
  content: counter(page, upper-romen);
}
section{
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="header">
<h1>
Widget Express
</h1>
</div>


<div id="footer">
<p class="page">
Page
</p>
</div>
<section>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</section>
</body>
```

Comment: section{
  margin: 100px auto 70px auto;
}

Comment: This works only for the first page.. on the second, header covers rest of text content from section..

Answer (score 0):

Providing images doesn't help much but looking at your code;
for "#header" and "#footer" you can set position:relative and whereit  says top, give different values and NOT the same values.

If you copy and paste your code, I can help you further

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0w75t98f/

In jsfiddle it will make only one page.. because i use dompdf i m making 2-3-4 pages and can't reproduce it on jsfiddle :(